# No response from URL in XML parsing using XMLMappable

Tags: swift, xml, xmlmapper

I am using [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) with Alamofire to map a response. So far I can map most of the response, except for the Image and and Duration. Here is a link to the XML RSS Feed: https://belizing.libsyn.com/rss. Any help on how to map the duration and image? 
This is my data model:

```
struct Image: XMLMappable {
    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    var nodeName: String!
    var image: String?

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        image <- map["image"]
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of your XML feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" 
    xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" 
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" 
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="https://belizing.libsyn.com/rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
        <title>Belize Travelcast</title>
        <pubDate>Thu, 28 Nov 2019 22:26:27 +0000</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 24 Dec 2019 02:21:22 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Libsyn WebEngine 2.0</generator>
        <link>https://belizing.com/podcast</link>
        <language>en</language>
        <copyright><![CDATA[Copyright Belizing.com]]></copyright>
        <docs>https://belizing.com/podcast</docs>
        <managingEditor>info@belizing.com (info@belizing.com)</managingEditor>
        <itunes:summary><![CDATA[The Belize Travelcast is the official podcast of Belize, a new podcast series created by Let’s Go Belizing Ltd. (Belizing.com), a brand that is passionate about telling authentic stories, promoting sustainable tourism, and traveling in Belize. Each episode is an engaging conversation that delivers useful and authentic travel tips and experience through personal stories from our guests. We also deliver relevant updates on the Belize tourism industry and important issues affecting the environment, culture, and economy of Belize. Find @goBelizing on social media.]]></itunes:summary>
        <image>
            <url>https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/7/8/5/f/785f5cd2268175a7/podcast-cover-art.png</url>
            <title>Belize Travelcast</title>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/podcast]]></link>
        </image>
        <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        <itunes:keywords>belize,belizing,travelbelize</itunes:keywords>
        <itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture">
            <itunes:category text="Places &amp; Travel"/>
        </itunes:category>
        <itunes:category text="Leisure"></itunes:category>
        <itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture"></itunes:category>
        <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/7/8/5/f/785f5cd2268175a7/podcast-cover-art.png" />
        <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:owner>
            <itunes:name><![CDATA[Belizing.com]]></itunes:name>
            <itunes:email>info@belizing.com</itunes:email>
        </itunes:owner>
        <description><![CDATA[The Belize Travelcast is the official podcast of Belize, a new podcast series created by Let’s Go Belizing Ltd. (Belizing.com), a brand that is passionate about telling authentic stories, promoting sustainable tourism, and traveling in Belize. Each episode is an engaging conversation that delivers useful and authentic travel tips and experience through personal stories from our guests. We also deliver relevant updates on the Belize tourism industry and important issues affecting the environment, culture, and economy of Belize. Find @goBelizing on social media.]]></description>
        <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[The Official Podcast of Belize]]></itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
        <item>
            <title>Backpacking in Belize: A Brazilian quit Law School and now Travels the World</title>
            <itunes:title>Backpacking in Belize: A Brazilian quit Law School and now Travels the World</itunes:title>
            <pubDate>Thu, 28 Nov 2019 22:26:27 +0000</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[2cf9cb25-3134-4188-8a62-ff77f0f148bf]]></guid>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/Belize-Travelcast-Episode-5/]]></link>
            <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/4/2/7/d/427d7f25e2d3d4cc/podcast-cover-art.png" />
            <description><![CDATA[<p>In this episode, we welcome Mayke Moraes as he travels through San Ignacio Belize. Mayke is a backpacker and leads what he calls a detached and minimalist lifestyle. With his backpack on his back, he visits places and revisits dreams that were born when he decided to leave his comfort zone in Brazil to build memories instead of material riches. Mayke is an accomplished author and social media influencer. Belize is the 70th country he has visited toward his goal of 100 countries. Listen to his story and hear why he plans to come back to Belize again.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>In this episode, we welcome Mayke Moraes as he travels through San Ignacio Belize. Mayke is a backpacker and leads what he calls a detached and minimalist lifestyle. With his backpack on his back, he visits places and revisits dreams that were born when he decided to leave his comfort zone in Brazil to build memories instead of material riches. Mayke is an accomplished author and social media influencer. Belize is the 70th country he has visited toward his goal of 100 countries. Listen to his story and hear why he plans to come back to Belize again.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure length="69477503" type="audio/mpeg" url="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/belizing/SouMochileiro-final.mp3?dest-id=1670078" />
            <itunes:duration>48:09</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:keywords>podcast,travel,backpacking,solo,belize,travelcast</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[Official Podcast of Belize]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>Mayke Moraes is a backpacker we met in San Ignacio Belize. He leads what he calls a detached and minimalist lifestyle. With his backpack on his back, he visits places and revisits dreams that were born when he decided to leave his comfort zone in Brazil to build memories instead of material riches. Mayke is an accomplished author and social media influencer. Belize is the 70th country he has visited toward his goal of 100 countries. Listen to his story and hear why he plans to come back to Belize again.</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
            <itunes:episode>5</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Enhancing the Belize Visitor Experience through Training</title>
            <itunes:title>Enhancing the Belize Visitor Experience through Training</itunes:title>
            <pubDate>Tue, 26 Nov 2019 23:41:32 +0000</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[c97fac35-daff-4648-ae54-2bbaff80996f]]></guid>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/Belize-Travelcast-Episode-4/]]></link>
            <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/5/b/d/5/5bd5f5318b982995/podcast-cover-art.png" />
            <description><![CDATA[<p>Jim Scott, the proprietor of Hospitality Training Services Belize discusses how hospitality service in Belize continues to improve. Jim talks about the array of upcoming brand-name resorts and hotel developments in Belize including Hilton, Marriott, Four Seasons, and others, and how it brings the need for improved service for visitors. Jim is a stalwart of the Belize Tourism Industry and is deeply passionate about uplifting the Belizean people by providing top-notch hospitality training in the industry.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Jim Scott, the proprietor of Hospitality Training Services Belize discusses how hospitality service in Belize continues to improve. Jim talks about the array of upcoming brand-name resorts and hotel developments in Belize including Hilton, Marriott, Four Seasons, and others, and how it brings the need for improved service for visitors. Jim is a stalwart of the Belize Tourism Industry and is deeply passionate about uplifting the Belizean people by providing top-notch hospitality training in the industry.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure length="44619380" type="audio/mpeg" url="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/belizing/jim-training-final.mp3?dest-id=1670078" />
            <itunes:duration>30:54</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:keywords>podcast,travel,belize,hospitality,travelcast</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[The Official Podcast of Belize]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>Jim Scott, the proprietor of Hospitality Training Services Belize discusses how hospitality service in Belize continues to improve. Jim talks about the array of upcoming brand-name resorts and hotel developments in Belize including Hilton, Marriott, Four Seasons, and others, and how it brings the need for improved service for visitors. Jim is a stalwart of the Belize Tourism Industry and is deeply passionate about uplifting the Belizean people by providing top-notch hospitality training in the industry.</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
            <itunes:episode>4</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>bonus</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>How a Lesson’s Motmot inspired a young Belizean to love Birds</title>
            <itunes:title>How a Lesson’s Motmot inspired a young Belizean to love Birds</itunes:title>
            <pubDate>Tue, 26 Nov 2019 23:23:46 +0000</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[19697220-b52a-4f38-816f-b29c0f35fe14]]></guid>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/Belize-Travelcast-Episode-3/]]></link>
            <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/5/1/f/a/51fa331ee357b949/podcast-cover-art.png" />
            <description><![CDATA[<p>In part two of our interview with the team from the Belize Raptor Center, we welcome lead bird trainer Marcia Mas, a native Belizean hailing from the Toledo district of Belize. Marcia talks about how her love for nature and the environment was nurtured from a young age by her parents growing up in southern Belize. She tells us that the Lesson’s motmot was the bird that made her fall in love with birding. Marcia is now the first certified female bird trainer in Belize and continues to inspire younger generations of birders through her educational outreach activities. Marcia was recently recognized as Belize’s Wonder Woman by the US Embassy of Belize, a well-deserved recognition for her hard work and dedication of preserving Belize’s birds and environment.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>In part two of our interview with the team from the Belize Raptor Center, we welcome lead bird trainer Marcia Mas, a native Belizean hailing from the Toledo district of Belize. Marcia talks about how her love for nature and the environment was nurtured from a young age by her parents growing up in southern Belize. She tells us that the Lesson’s motmot was the bird that made her fall in love with birding. Marcia is now the first certified female bird trainer in Belize and continues to inspire younger generations of birders through her educational outreach activities. Marcia was recently recognized as Belize’s Wonder Woman by the US Embassy of Belize, a well-deserved recognition for her hard work and dedication of preserving Belize’s birds and environment.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure length="25433967" type="audio/mpeg" url="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/belizing/Mauricia-Mas-final.mp3?dest-id=1670078" />
            <itunes:duration>17:34</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:keywords>podcast,travel,birds,birding,belize,travelcast</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[Official Podcast of Belize]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>We welcome lead bird trainer from the Belize Raptor Center, Marcia Mas, a native Belizean from the Toledo district of Belize. Marcia talks about how her love for nature and the environment was nurtured from a young age by her parents growing up in southern Belize. Learn how the Lesson’s motmot was the bird that made her fall in love with birding. She is now the first certified female bird trainer in Belize and continues to inspire younger generations of birders through her educational outreach activities.</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
            <itunes:episode>3</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Belize Birds of Prey. Sarah and the Orange Breasted Falcon</title>
            <itunes:title>Belize Birds of Prey. Sarah and the Orange Breasted Falcon</itunes:title>
            <pubDate>Mon, 25 Nov 2019 19:21:58 +0000</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[24678dac-9eed-42d2-91d3-d83f84c348e5]]></guid>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/Belize-Travelcast-Episode-2/]]></link>
            <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/f/3/5/f/f35fa01fd85bbc45/podcast-cover-art.png" />
            <description><![CDATA[<p>In this episode, we welcome Sarah Mann from the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah talks about her love for birds of prey and her journey to Belize first as a student volunteer and now as the director of the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah points out the Orange Breasted Falcon as the bird that convinced her that Belize was where she wanted to live. Hear the story of how she got her first lifer in Belize as soon as she landed at the airport. In this episode, Sarah also talks about the importance of having a care and rehabilitation center for birds in Belize and some of the educational outreach that she and her team does. This is part 1 of a 2-part series with the Belize Raptor Center.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>In this episode, we welcome Sarah Mann from the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah talks about her love for birds of prey and her journey to Belize first as a student volunteer and now as the director of the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah points out the Orange Breasted Falcon as the bird that convinced her that Belize was where she wanted to live. Hear the story of how she got her first lifer in Belize as soon as she landed at the airport. In this episode, Sarah also talks about the importance of having a care and rehabilitation center for birds in Belize and some of the educational outreach that she and her team does. This is part 1 of a 2-part series with the Belize Raptor Center.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure length="30853458" type="audio/mpeg" url="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/belizing/sarah-mann-updated.mp3?dest-id=1670078" />
            <itunes:duration>21:20</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:keywords>podcast,travel,belize,belizing,travelcast</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[In this episode, we welcome Sarah Mann from the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah talks about her love for birds of prey and her journey to Belize first as a student volunteer and now as the director of the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah points out the Orange...]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>Sarah from the Belize Raptor Center discusses her journey to Belize and how the Belize Raptor Center came about from her love of Birds. Sarah talks about her love for birds of prey and her journey to Belize first as a student volunteer and now as the director of the Belize Raptor Center. Sarah points out the Orange Breasted Falcon as the bird that convinced her that Belize was where she wanted to live. Hear the story of how she got her first lifer in Belize as soon as she landed at the airport.</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
            <itunes:episode>2</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>From Michigan to Belize with Love. A Peace Corps volunteer came to Belize in 1987 and never left.</title>
            <itunes:title>From Michigan to Belize with Love. A Peace Corps volunteer came to Belize in 1987 and never left.</itunes:title>
            <pubDate>Fri, 08 Nov 2019 00:09:09 +0000</pubDate>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[78563602fbbb49b8892634ec47adf6a1]]></guid>
            <link><![CDATA[https://belizing.com/Belize-Travelcast-Episode-1/]]></link>
            <itunes:image href="https://ssl-static.libsyn.com/p/assets/5/b/9/2/5b92c01b31732b86/podcast-cover-art.png" />
            <description><![CDATA[<p>Host Javier Gutierrez is joined by Jim Scott for a discussion about his journey to Belize and what made him stay in Belize after coming as a peace corps volunteer in 1987. Jim recounts his time in Belize City and how he assimilated into the culture of Belize and fell in love with the people. They discuss his love of nature and his experiences as a scuba diver, fly fisherman, avid hiker, and a professional in the Belize tourism industry. Jim is an advocate for hospitality training in Belize and together with Lorena Zaldana they own and operate Hospitality Training Services Belize which offers hospitality training and certification in Belize and around the world. They are also the proprietors of the 501Hub, a new restaurant in Belize City which also serves as a training hub for restaurant staff.</p>]]></description>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Host Javier Gutierrez is joined by Jim Scott for a discussion about his journey to Belize and what made him stay in Belize after coming as a peace corps volunteer in 1987. Jim recounts his time in Belize City and how he assimilated into the culture of Belize and fell in love with the people. They discuss his love of nature and his experiences as a scuba diver, fly fisherman, avid hiker, and a professional in the Belize tourism industry. Jim is an advocate for hospitality training in Belize and together with Lorena Zaldana they own and operate Hospitality Training Services Belize which offers hospitality training and certification in Belize and around the world. They are also the proprietors of the 501Hub, a new restaurant in Belize City which also serves as a training hub for restaurant staff.</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <enclosure length="54515233" type="audio/mpeg" url="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/belizing/Pilot-Episode-JimScott-final.mp3?dest-id=1670078" />
            <itunes:duration>37:17</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:keywords>podcast,travel,vacation,belize,travelcast</itunes:keywords>
            <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[Host Javier Gutierrez is joined by Jim Scott for a discussion about his journey to Belize and what made him stay in Belize after coming as a peace corps volunteer in 1987. Jim recounts his time in Belize City and how he assimilated into the culture of...]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>Host Javier Gutierrez is joined by Jim Scott for a discussion about his journey to Belize and what made him stay in Belize after coming as a peace corps volunteer in 1987. Jim recounts his time in Belize City and how he assimilated into the culture of Belize and fell in love with the people. They discuss his love of nature and his experiences as a scuba diver, fly fisherman, avid hiker, and a professional in the Belize tourism industry</itunes:summary>
            <itunes:season>1</itunes:season>
            <itunes:episode>1</itunes:episode>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:author>Belizing.com</itunes:author>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

And here is a model structure in which you can map it:

```
struct RSS: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var channel: Channel?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        channel <- map["channel"]
    }
}

struct Channel: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var atomLink: AtomLink?
    var title: String?
    var pubDate: Date?
    var lastBuildDate: String?
    var generator: String?
    var link: String?
    var language: String?
    var copyright: String?
    var docs: String?
    var managingEditor: String?
    var itunesSummary: String?
    var image: Image?
    var itunesAuthor: String?
    var itunesKeywords: String?
    var itunesCategories: [ItunesCategory]?
    var itunesImage: ItunesImage?
    var itunesΕxplicit: String?
    var itunesΟwner: ItunesOwner?
    var description: String?
    var itunesSubtitle: String?
    var itunesType: String?
    var items: [Item]?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        atomLink <- map["atom:link"]
        title <- map["title"]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        pubDate <- (map["pubDate"], XMLDateFormatterTransform(dateFormatter: dateFormatter))
        lastBuildDate <- map["lastBuildDate"]
        generator <- map["generator"]
        link <- map["link"]
        language <- map["language"]
        copyright <- map["copyright"]
        docs <- map["docs"]
        managingEditor <- map["managingEditor"]
        itunesSummary <- map["itunes:summary"]
        image <- map["image"]
        itunesAuthor <- map["itunes:author"]
        itunesKeywords <- map["itunes:keywords"]
        itunesCategories <- map["itunes:category"]
        itunesImage <- map["itunes:image"]
        itunesΕxplicit <- map["itunes:explicit"]
        itunesΟwner <- map["itunes:owner"]
        description <- map["description"]
        itunesSubtitle <- map["itunes:subtitle"]
        itunesType <- map["itunes:type"]
        items <- map["item"]
    }
}

struct AtomLink: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var href: URL?
    var rel: String?
    var type: String?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        href <- (map.attributes["href"], XMLURLTransform())
        rel <- map.attributes["rel"]
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
    }
}

struct Image: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var url: URL?
    var title: String?
    var link: String?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        url <- (map["url"], XMLURLTransform())
        title <- map["title"]
        link <- map["link"]
    }
}

class ItunesCategory: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var text: String?
    var itunesCategory: ItunesCategory?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        text <- map.attributes["text"]
        itunesCategory <- map["itunes:category"]
    }
}

struct ItunesImage: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var href: URL?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        href <- (map.attributes["href"], XMLURLTransform())
    }
}

struct ItunesOwner: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var itunesName: String?
    var itunesEmail: String?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        itunesName <- map["itunes:name"]
        itunesEmail <- map["itunes:email"]
    }
}

struct Item: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var title: String?
    var itunesTitle: String?
    var pubDate: Date?
    var guid: Guid?
    var link: String?
    var itunesImage: ItunesImage?
    var description: String?
    var contentEncoded: String?
    var enclosure: Enclosure?
    var itunesDuration: String?
    var itunesExplicit: String?
    var itunesKeywords: String?
    var itunesSubtitle: String?
    var itunesSummary: String?
    var itunesSeason: String?
    var itunesEpisode: String?
    var itunesEpisodeType: String?
    var itunesAuthor: String?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        itunesTitle <- map["itunes:title"]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        pubDate <- (map["pubDate"], XMLDateFormatterTransform(dateFormatter: dateFormatter))
        guid <- map["guid"]
        link <- map["link"]
        itunesImage <- map["itunes:image"]
        description <- map["description"]
        contentEncoded <- map["content:encoded"]
        enclosure <- map["enclosure"]
        itunesDuration <- map["itunes:duration"]
        itunesExplicit <- map["itunes:explicit"]
        itunesKeywords <- map["itunes:keywords"]
        itunesSubtitle <- map["itunes:subtitle"]
        itunesSummary <- map["itunes:summary"]
        itunesSeason <- map["itunes:season"]
        itunesEpisode <- map["itunes:episode"]
        itunesEpisodeType <- map["itunes:episodeType"]
        itunesAuthor <- map["itunes:author"]
    }
}

struct Guid: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var isPermaLink: Bool?
    var value: String?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        isPermaLink <- map.attributes["isPermaLink"]
        value <- map.innerText
    }
}

struct Enclosure: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var length: String?
    var type: String?
    var url: URL?

    init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        length <- map.attributes["length"]
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
        url <- (map.attributes["url"], XMLURLTransform())
    }
}
```